# Need to get data from (laravel api) using fetch then parse it on to another function

Tags: javascript, php, reactjs, laravel, react-admin

I am a beginner at React. I fetch data in an application using (Laravel API) and manipulate it.
But the data is only available within the function scope.
How can I retrieve it outside the function and using it somewhere else?
How it will be possible?

```
//Function to get data from API
var userId = localStorage.getItem("userid")
const OrderStoryIds = fetch(`${"/api/v1/order?user_id=" + userId}`,{
        headers:{
            Authorization: "bearer " + localStorage.getItem("token")
    }}).then((response) => response.json()).then((order) => {
        var record={};
        if(order !== null) {
            order.forEach(function (items, index) {
                record[items.story_id]= items.status    
            });
        }
    return record
});
const printOrderStoryId = (id) => {
    OrderStoryIds.then((result) => {
        console.log(result[id]);
        var isAlreadyPurchased = result[id] === 1? true: false;
        console.log(isAlreadyPurchased);
        return isAlreadyPurchased;
});
};

const StoriesShow = (props, { key }) => {
        return (
            <div className="col-md-4" key={key}>
//This is where I want to call the above function and use the result for further use/something
            <div className="image-prinze">
                <img src={require('../../../../../public/images/frontend/' + props.image)} alt="" />
                {printOrderStoryId(props.id)? (
                   <div className="button-prinze">
                        <a href={'/storydetail/' + props.id} className="btn btn-prinze">Mehr erfahren</a>
                </div>): 
                (<div className="button-prinze">
                <span className="btn btn-prinze">already purchased</span>
        </div>)}
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`fetch()` is asynchronous so you can't simply return the variable outside of the function scope. However, there are workarounds:

```js
var myVar = null;

fetch('http://example.com').then(function(data) {
    myVar = data.myVar
});

// your render should run when variables change
render() {
    return (myVar ?? 'not fetched yet');
}
```

Make sure, that (as shown above) at initial render the value of `myVar` is `null` and is only filled on subsequent calls. So your `render()` method must not rely on `myVar` having a value.

Answer (score 0):

```
yourMethod = (event) => {
      event.preventDefault();
      fetch(`/route_to_your_method_api/${id}`)
        .then((resp) => resp.json())
        .then(function(data) {
          //posible loading
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
          console.log(error);
        });
      }
```